# how to make non-GUI MFC application?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, visual-c++-2010

I did a project based on MFC, it has GUI of course. Now i need to change it to non-Gui. So, whenever i start build the project, it should run in the background rather to show GUI.

I hope my question is clear. Kindly suggest me . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the easiest thing to do as a retrofit. Easiest approach would be to make the UI hidden by using ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) on the main window (and any secondary windows and the equivalent for any other UI elements).

Comment: MFC is a wrapper around the Win32 API... Check out MSDN for CWnd::ShowWindow

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply create conslole application with MFC support and make it a Windows seervice?